# Missing artifacts for openzeppelin contracts with hardhat

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, solc, hardhat, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm using [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) to write a dapp.
As I'm compiling my dapp I'm getting an error:

```
Error HH700: Artifact for contract "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol:OwnableUpgradeable" not found.
```

My dapp has some dependencies to openzeppelin contracts but not to this specific one.
I added the required import and then got the same error, this time with `@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol`.

Added the required import and got the same with `@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/AccessControlUpgradeable.sol`/

After adding those 3 imports the dapp finally compiled.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/AccessControlUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

This dapp went through some phases and had in the past dependencies to those imported contracts but now it doesn't.
The problem started when I deleted the artifacts folder and tried to compile. The compiler is right - those contracts can't be found in the artifacts folder but also my dapp doesn't really use them, so what would the compiler ask for them?

I'm using solidity 0.8.6.

Comment: Potentially related: [hardhat-dependency-compiler](https://github.com/ItsNickBarry/hardhat-dependency-compiler).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gm. Have you tried with `npx hardhat clean` before compiling?
It will clear the cache and delete all artifacts.

[Source](https://hardhat.org/guides/compile-contracts.html#compiling-your-contracts)